# Toolbar Bar Button Item has no options for IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I'm trying to drag a **Bar Button Item** from Interface Builder to the **View Controller** class in the `viewController.swift` file, but there is no option to choose connection as an **IBAction**.

I need to connect them as **IBActions**, but it only shows options for Outlet and Outlet collections.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the selector of **Send Actions` in Interface Builder to your class file

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help but the is no name selector in the options here is a picture [IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/2qwl8xf.png[/IMG]

Comment: select the controller in you nib, that open the right column and activate the last tab. In the bottom of this tab you should find the sent actions. Drag from the circle to you element

Comment: @EdwinBilla: From the image it is clear that, you've selected the toolbar, not the bar button item.

Comment: Thank you Very Much @MidhunMP